# CreateProcess returns non 0 but GetExitCodeProcess() returns 128

Tags: windows, process, createprocess, exit-code

I am creating an application that will start another process using CreateProcess(). And in the parent process I will use GetExitCodeProcess() to check whether the process active or not.

Here CreateProcess() is successful (returned a non negative value) but GetExitCodeProcess() returns 128 (There are no child processes to wait for). I am not seeing any trace of the child process started(usually some debugs). It happens intermittently.

Any idea what really happened to the child process?. Where we get more information (in system/application event logs?).

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: The documentation for [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) tends to indicate that any value other the 259 is going to be program specific. (Assuming `GetExitCodeProcess` was successful)

Comment: Error checking code very rarely gets tested.  Or reviewed when you don't let anybody look at it.

Comment: CreateProcess returns zero, not a negative number, on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

I have found the following MSDN articles that gives the same symptoms and resolution for the problem.

---

Cmd.exe, Perl.exe, or other console-mode applications may fail to initialize properly and terminate prematurely when launched by a service using the CreateProcess() or CreateProcessAsUser() APIs. The calling process has no way of knowing that the launched console-mode application has terminated prematurely.

In some instances, calling GetExitCode() against the failed process indicates the following exit code:
128L ERROR_WAIT_NO_CHILDREN - There are no child processes to wait for.

---

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156484
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142676/EN-US

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175687/EN-US

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: Those articles apply to Windows NT 4, they are unlikely to be related to your issue.